# SendGrid "To" List email ids visible to everyone in the list

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application, email, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid to send emails to a list of users through a console application in asp.net. I am sending a list of user's email addresses in the AddTo section while sending an email. The code looks like this:

`SendGridMessage message = new SendGridMessage();

 message.AddTo(new List<string>() { "user1@abc.com", "user2@xyz.com", "user3@abc.com", "user4@xyz.com" });`

The email is sent as expected, but in the "To" section of the email, I am able to see all the email ids of users to whom this email was sent(image attached below). I want the email ids to be hidden so that no one misuses the other email ids in the list. Is there anyway I can accomplish this using SendGrid? 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use .AddBcc() instead of .AddTo(). BUT if you do this then you'll have to set the To address to something like "no-reply@example.com" which isn't ideal and might increase the chances of the message ending up in the SPAM or Junk folders of your users.

SO instead, write a for loop to send the email per user.

```
var emailAddresses = new List<string>() { "user1@abc.com", "user2@xyz.com", "user3@abc.com", "user4@xyz.com" };

for (var emailAddress in emailAddresses)
{
     var email = new SendGridMessage();

     email.AddTo(emailAddress);

     // set other values such as the email contact

     // send/deliver email
}
```

Is the content of the email message the same for everyone? I would assume each person would have different "monthly usage" amounts and if so the for loop would be better...

Answer (score 2):

To send to multiple recipients in SendGrid without them seeing each other, you want to use the [X-SMTPAPI header](https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-csharp), as opposed to the native SMTP To header.

```
var header = new Header();

var recipients = new List<String> {"a@example.com", "b@exampe.com", "c@example.com"};
header.SetTo(recipients);

var subs = new List<String> {"A","B","C"};
header.AddSubstitution("%name%", subs);

var mail = new MailMessage
{
    From = new MailAddress("please-reply@example.com"),
    Subject = "Welcome",
    Body = "Hi there %name%"
};

// add the custom header that we built above
mail.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", header.JsonString());
```

The SMTPAPI header will be parsed by SendGrid, and each recipient will get sent a distinct single-To message.

Comment: This would be applicable if using SmtpClient and MailMessage classes. The OP is using SendGridMessage. If the OP changes his code to use SmtpClient and MailMessage classes then this would work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use personalization for that, there are 2 options:

```
var message = new SendGridMessage();
message.Personalizations = new List<Personalization>();    
foreach(var email in emails)
{
    var personalization = new Personalization();
    personalization.AddTo(new Email(email));
}
```

Or:

```
var message = new SendGridMessage();
foreach(var email in emails)
    message.AddTo(email, emails.IndexOf(email));
```

Alternatively you can also use MailHelper with the showAllRecipients flag:

```
MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients()
```